# What is second derivative of Guassian?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I want to find edge magnitude at each pixel of my image and for that I need to apply second derivative of Guassian filter. I am using Sobel for that. Is it correct or should I use some other filter ?

```
 Sobel(src,magY,CV_32F,0,1,size);
```

This is the image

[image]

It is written in the Algorithm that steerable-filter used is the second derivative of the
Gaussian. And by plotting the edge magnitude the output that came

[image]

I was trying to use Sobel, but am not getting this output. I also tried Laplacian but output is not similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

To find edge magnitude (like the very basic edge detection methods) you can simply apply a gaussian using "imfilter"
like in

```
filter = fspecial('gaussian',h,sigma); %create a gaussian filter
filtered = imfilter(img, filter);  %gaussian convolved with image
figure;imshow(filtered,[]);        %you can see a blurred version of your image
[fx,fy] = gradient(filtered);      %take that blurred image's derivative
```

Then find the magnitude of the derivative like in

```
edgemap = fx.*fx + fy.*fy;
```

You can normalize this edgemap or apply thresholding if you wish.

Comment: But I need, second derivative. gradient(filtered) will provide single derivative only, right ?

Comment: yes, if f(x,y) is a function, then gradient(f) gives df/dx and df/dy. If f(x,y) is I(x,y) (the image) then I_x and I_y are max at edges by applying a thresholding on gradient magnitude you get the edges. This is equivalent to  ||\nabla(I)||^2. Can you explain why you need second derivative for edge detection?

Comment: btw, if by second derivative you mean laplacian, then it is way easier. You simply do "del2(filtered)" and it gives you laplacian of blurred image. (instead of Sobel operator)

Comment: Actually its given in the algorithm, that the result will be much better by using second derivative. I just want to know whether Sobel performed second derivative operation or as you suggest I should use Laplacian.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 2nd derivative of Gaussian? If you are trying to edge magnitude at each pixel of your image, you can apply Difference of Gaussian, which is basically the difference between 2 gaussian blurred image, each blurred it's own sigma/ kernel size. A c++ code showing the DoG method using kernel size of 3 and 1 is as shown:

```
cv::GaussianBlur(imagep,image1, cv::Size(3,3), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT ); 
cv::GaussianBlur(imagep,image2, cv::Size(1,1), 0, 0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT );
finalImage=image2-image1;
```

The difference will be the edges left, as DoG is a bandpass, high frequency noises are filtered out and low frequencies that lies outside the lower limit of the band pass will be the homogenous part of your object. So whatever within the band will be the edges left.

From there you should be able to find your edge magnitude.

Hope that helped you somehow. If you need more help, or this is not what you are asking, feel free to comment, and I will try my best to reply asap(:

Comment: I had added more information. Hope it help. And I also tried the GausssianBlur that you had described but not getting desired output. Thanks